# How to change PowerShell culture in an Azure Function

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, cultureinfo, culture

I have written a script where i use Swedish characters ("åäö"), it is deployed to an Azure function.

When the script runs it is supposed to output this text: "Förvaltning" but i get this instead: "FÃ¶rvaltning".

I tried changing the culture of Powershell by including **Set-Culture** i the beginning of the script. But it doesn't change the culture.

Anyone know how to do this for a PowerShell Script running in an Azure Function?

This code runs to set the variable "prefixTitle".
[image]

This is then logged to the "Logs", when i write "Write-Output".
[image]

Comment: Can you show us the script (or perhaps a trimmed-down version that shows this specific behavior)?

Comment: I doubt Set-Culture can influence that. Most likely, this is a matter of encoding and this depends on how exactly you are observing this text. For example, if you just use the auto-generated HTTP trigger function and return "Förvaltning" in the body of an HTTP response, this is what the client will receive. But displaying these characters properly depends on the client. So, where do you see the incorrectly encoded text?

Comment: Added more information to the post. it is either culture or encoding. But i don't know how to change the encoding of PowerShell Scripts running with Azure Function.

Comment: When you say "This is then logged to the "Logs", when i write "Write-Output"." Is that Console when function runs in your local machine or in Azure streaming log?

Comment: @krishg Azure streaming log

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with your browser side encoding in the sense how it is rendering utf-8, and not Function side. I ran my powershell sample function without setting anything in the function code. Both log output and http response looks ok as below.

[image]

Comment: The thing is that i am creating a SharePoint Online Site and i use the word "Förvaltning" in the title of the site. Because of this the title of the site is set with wrong character.

If i run this script locally on my computer with Visual Studio Code, there i can set what encoding i want to use, that fixes the problem running the script locally but in an azure function i don't know where i can change this setting.

Comment: What I meant is the Function already returns the text correctly when I ran it to return  "Förvaltning". So I don't think you need to do anything at Function side.